# repeat a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

for example I have a vector

```
  x=[1 0 0];
```

I want to triple it

```
   x=[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
```

I know this way

```
    new_x=[x,x,x];
```

but if I want to do it 200 times not 3 times I will not write x for 200 times in new vector.
So I am asking you to give me an easier solution.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `repmat`:

```
new_x = repmat(x,1,3)
```